# Setting autopostback to true in itemTemplate in gridview slows down databind

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox

I have an asp grid view. One of the fields is an "ItemTemplate" I bind this dynamically using an in memory datatable and linq to filter this depending on other factors.

If I leave the markup as such

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectSite" runat="server" />
```

The databind takes about 0.5 seconds for 500ish rows.

If I add

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectSite" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

The same EXACT databind takes roughly 10/15 seconds with no other change to the code. Is there any reason this would be happening or any way to avoid this? I really need to postback on the checkbox to get when the checkedChange is fired for each row in the grid.

Comment: I don't think that this will cause it to be 20 times slower since it just inserts this for every row (500 times): `OnChange="__doPostBack('chkSelectSite','')" `. Why do you need to show all 500 rows? You could use paging.

Comment: You could enable tracing to see why is taking so long. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll try some tracing, but that is the only thing I change and it takes roughly 20 times longer... I'm as confused as you. No server side code changes at all, just adding the autopostback causes a slow down.

Comment: I had toyed with paging, but the nature of the data from a user point of view is that it would be easier to see it all in one place as opposed to paging. As there are lots of checkboxes, I would then have to manage the selected checkboxes across pages in the session/viewstate as well.

Comment: So wouldn't a manual postback as soon as a checkbox is checked suit your needs?

Comment: So... you mean, add a client side method and get javascript to do the post back?

Comment: I manually added  `OnChange="__doPostBack('chkSelectSite','')"` to the markup, and it databinds quickly. But checking the checkbox is causing a full postback and isn't being "picked up" by the ajax updatepanel it's sitting in.